# How to pass a URL parameter to a rendered symfony3 form?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

If I embed a controller in a twig template, how do I pass a required URL parameter to the rendered embedded route?

In the following example, the Image belongs to an Album, and needs the album Id (it's part of a composite key)

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <td>{{ album.id }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td>{{ album.name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {{ render(controller(
                'AppBundle:Image:new',
                {'album': album}
            )) }}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The Image:new route is prefixed with the following annotation

```
 * @Route("{album}/image")
```

The method is as follows

```
    public function newAction(Request $request, $album)
{
    $image = new Image();
    $form = $this->createForm(
        'AppBundle\Form\ImageUploadType',
            $image,
            [
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('image_new'),
                'method' => 'POST',
            ]
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($image);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('image_show', array('id' => $image->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('image/new.html.twig', array(
        'image' => $image,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Rendering the template that we have embedded that form into results in the following error;

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("album") to generate a URL for route "image_new".").

What is the correct way to pass URL parameters to embedded controllers with symfony3.2 and twig?

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from the embed of the controller? `'action' => $this->generateUrl('image_new'),`, here the mandatory parameter is missing. Since it's an embed the rendering causes the problem but not necessary the cal to embed directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error Symfony is throwing is not about passing the ID, but about URL building.

In your code, you have this fragment:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    'AppBundle\Form\ImageUploadType',
        $image,
        [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('image_new'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ]
);
```

While it should be:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    'AppBundle\Form\ImageUploadType',
        $image,
        [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('image_new',['album'=>$album,]),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ]
);
```

Just pass the album to the `generateUrl` method.